# Examples of mapping two sets where if the two sets are isomorphic doesn't imply that mapping is also 1 to 1

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am struggling with getting an example of two sets S and T and (onto) mapping f, where the fact S and T are isomorphic does not imply that f is also 1 - 1. If possible could you also give an example in which the fact that they are isomorphic would imply that they are 1 - 1?

Thank You!

Comment: What is the map $f$ doing? Do you mean to say "$S$ and $T$ are isomorphic under $f$"? If so, $f$ must be 1-1, as this is part of the definition of isomorphism.

Comment: Let $S$ and $T$ be two one-element sets. Then there is a unique function $S \to T$ and it is bijective. Conversely, if $S$ and $T$ are in bijection but there is a map $S \to T$ which is not bijective, then $T$ must contain at least two elements.

Comment: Any old $f$ between two isomorphic sets need not be a witness to the fact that $S$ and $T$ are isomorphic, so it does not have to be 1-to-1. E.g., $S=\{a,b\}$, $T=\{1,2\}$ are bijectable/isomorphic as sets, but $f\colon S\to T$ given by $f(a)=f(b)=1$ is a perfectly fine function that is not 1-to-1.

Comment: To combine Zhen and Arturo's answers: a constant function on a set of more than one element will do the trick.

Comment: @IAmBrianDawkins It seems Jeff wanted a function that is onto but not one-to-one, in which case Zhen and Arturo's answers apply only to sets of 2 elements. The function $h:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $h=c$ is certainly not onto.

Comment: @barf Thank you for pointing that out.  The revision history indicates that "(onto)" might have been added after I commented.

Comment: @Iambriandawkins Ah, I will be sure to check that next time before 'correcting'!

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Can you do this for finite $T$ and $S$? What happens if $T$ and $S$ are infinite? Think of shift-like maps  $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 3):

Consider the map $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ given by
$$\begin{aligned} 1 &\mapsto 1,\\
                  2 &\mapsto 1,\\
                  3 &\mapsto 2,\\
                  4 &\mapsto 3, \\
                  5 &\mapsto 4,\\
                     & \ \ \vdots\end{aligned}$$
ie 
$$f(n) = \begin{cases}
                        1 &\text{ if } n =1,\\
                        n - 1 &\text{ otherwise.} \end{cases} $$

Answer (score 1):

The comments and answer so far given seem to ignore the requirement that $f$ be onto. Here’s an example that takes that into account. Take $S=T=\mathbb{N}$, and let $$f:S\to T:n\mapsto \left\lfloor\frac{n}2\right\rfloor.$$ You should be able without too much trouble to show that $f$ us surjective (maps $S$ onto $T$) and is two-to-one everywhere. (E.g., $f(8) = f(9) = 4$.)